# Is there any way to achieve Connection Pool on Inbound gateway(Channel) in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

```
@Bean
public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(port);
    serverConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new InboundCustomStxEtxHeaderLengthSerializer());
    serverConnectionFactory.setSerializer(new InboundCustomStxEtxHeaderLengthSerializer());
    // serverConnectionFactory.setSoTcpNoDelay(true);
    // serverConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
    // serverConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    // serverConnectionFactory.setSoTimeout(50000);
    serverConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
    serverConnectionFactory.setBacklog(4000);
    return serverConnectionFactory;
}
```

Connection Pooling on AbstractServerConnectionFactory

Comment: Not sure what is the question. The server side opens a server socket and performs `this.serverSocket.accept()` in a `while (true) {` loop. This client socket is wrapped into a `Connection` abstraction and passed to the `Executor` for execution. What else you'd like to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.